# How to create a thirdlevel CA in Step?

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl, certificate-authority

Step allows to use an existing root-certificate using `step ca init --root=a.crt --key=a.key`. In that case step generates an intermediate certificate for later use. However, my root certificate was already used before for generating certificates outside of step.

The idea to solve this without serial-clashes in the "A"-CA is an intermediate CA "B" which can then be used by step as root. However this causes issues while running step, as step does not not nothing about the "A"-CA. I would expect step creating another intermediate signed by "B" like so:

```
A        my old root, used for other manually managed certificates
\-B      a new CA certificate, managed manually
  \-C    Step's intermediate CA
```

Is there a way to achive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running a thirdlevel CA is possible, but not needed with the reason "serial-clashes". The signature of the step-controlled CA can be done also by `A` and step does not need control the root, it just creates one by default, which can be replaced together with the intermediate as written in [the questions page](https://github.com/smallstep/certificates/blob/master/docs/questions.md#i-already-have-pki-in-place-can-i-use-this-with-my-own-root-certificate):

> [...] First, `step-ca` does not actually need the root CA signing key. So you can simply remove that file [...]

The solution is just to replace the root and the intermediate certificate (including the latter key) before using step as CA.